# Primefaces - elements not rendered with layout

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces

I'm using PF 4.0 and I'm trying to use templating and dialog. This is my template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head></h:head>

  <h:body>  

    <p:growl for="message" id="msg" showDetail="true" />

    <p:layout id="page" fullPage="true">

      <!-- North -->
      <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="150px" style="border: none !important">
        <h:form id="menutoolbar">
        <p:toolbar>  
          [...]
        </p:toolbar>
        </h:form>
      </p:layoutUnit>

      <!-- Center -->
      <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border: none !important">
        <ui:insert name="content">Center of page</ui:insert>
      </p:layoutUnit>

      <!-- South -->
      <p:layoutUnit position="south" collapsible="false" gutter="0">
        <ui:insert name="status"></ui:insert>
      </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>

  </h:body> 

</html>
```

I'm using the template to render another page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head></h:head>

  <h:body>  

    <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="id_file" value="#{csvDetalleBean.idFile}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:composition template="./baseTemplate.xhtml">

      <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="tableform" prependId="false">              
          <p:dataTable id="detalle" value="#{csvDetalleBean.tableModel}" var="row" selection="#{csvDetalleBean.selectedRows}">
            [...columns definition...]
          </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
      </ui:define>        

      <ui:define name="status">
        <h:form id="statusform">
          <p:panel id="panel" header="Status" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            [...controls definitions...]
          </p:panel>  
          <p:poll interval="20" async="true" update="panel" />
        </h:form>
      </ui:define>

      <p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="respuestasDialog" resizable="false" appendToBody="true">  
          <p:dataTable id="respuestas" value="#{transactions.rows}" var="trRow">
            <p:column headerText="Confirmation number">  
              <h:outputText value="#{trRow.get('confirmation_nm')}" /> hola
            </p:column>  
          </p:dataTable>
      </p:dialog>  

    </ui:composition>      

  </h:body>
</html>
```

The point is that I cannot show the dialog because it is not rendered at all. I think the point is the composition tag, I've already tried to put the dialog outside the composition, with same results.
What's the correct way to put components outside the layout? Of course don't want to put the dialog inside the template.
Thank you very much!

Comment: THe primefaces dialog doesn't work inside the layout. Try set dialog property "appendToBody" to true.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As you can see in the code above I've already set appendToBody="true"

Comment: Sorry , I must have missed it.